# ember custom select. How can I create isolated scope for selected element?

Tags: ember.js

I found custom select for ember
https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/6320922 . It's based on components and works well. 
But I have one trouble. Data source for select is shared between all instances of it. 
And I want to set default value as the first element of the data set but when I change value in one select it changes everywhere. Can you help me with it? Here is example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guhobutafado/19/edit

Answer (score 1):

In your example, your select boxes all refer to the same data set with binding, so, of course, when one changes, all of them do... That's the principle of data-binding.

Then you have to use different data sets for your problem, to save the modifications on each select. Without this, you can't access to the data on each one, because they point to the same *thing*.

You can use multiple arrays like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Route.extend({
  name: 'one',
  className: 'dropdown',
  choices1: [
    { choice: 'Choose One' },
    { choice: 'First' },
    { choice: 'Last' }
  ],
  choices2: [
    { choice: 'Choose One' },
    { choice: 'First' },
    { choice: 'Last' }
  ],
  choices3: [
    { choice: 'Choose One' },
    { choice: 'First' },
    { choice: 'Last' }
  ]
});
```

Then call your *faux-select* components with each independent array:

```
{{faux-select name=name className=model.className
  choices=choices1 selected=choices1.[0].choice}}

{{faux-select name=name className=model.className
  choices=choices2 selected=choices2.[0].choice}}

{{faux-select name=name className=model.className
  choices=choices3 selected=choices3.[0].choice}}
```

[Here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viseb/1/)'s a JSBin with this philosophy in action.